# Why is dd command limiting dummy file size at 2GB?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, dd, fedora20

I'm just curious about why the dd command is limiting the size of a dummy file to about 2.1GB

```
[aesteban@localhost ~]$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=3G count=1
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
2147479552 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 10.0044 s, 215 MB/s
[aesteban@localhost ~]$ ls -sh test.img 
2.0G test.img
```

I seen above I specified 3GB but  the file is only 2.1GB, any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Which filesystem do you use ? Each of them has its own limits, FAT for example will hit the 2GB limit. And out of curiosity: what happens when you specify `bs=1G` and `count=4` ?

Comment: looks like ext4 per `df -ht`, changing the count to 2 made the file 4GB :) so it seems to be a `dd` thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can suppose that that's a limitation of dd buffer size, just try to split it by setting `bs=1Gb` `count=3`

Answer (score 3):

In order to use files larger than 2GB, you need kernel support, filesystem support, and usually application support. If any of those requirements are not met, you can't exceed 2GB.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/24804) from serverfault may be of help.